# i want to transpose the column into rows

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have my data in redshift sql server like:

```
MatchId TeamId  Teamname  Home/away  Teamstats  statsvalue
1          101     a          home      yards      0
1          101     a          home      firstdown  1
1          101     a          home      points     2
1          101     a          home      completion 4
1          202     b          away      sacks      3
1          202     b          away      penalties  5
1          202     b          away      yards      6
1          202     b          away      points     7
```

I want the data to be like:

```
MatchId TeamId  Teamname  Home/away  yards  firstdown points completion sacks penalties 
1          101     a          home     0       1        2        4        3       5
1          202     b          away     6       null     7         null    null    null
```

Comment: From a quick google redshift is Postgresql not Microsoft SQL Server. Is that correct? If so please remove the sql-server tag.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need a `pivot`

```
Select *
from yourtable
pivot (max(statsvalue) for teamstats in 
     (yards, firstdown, points, completion, sacks, penalties) 
) p
```

Comment: Is that supported on redshift?

Comment: @MartinSmith No idea! It's supported on SQL Server as per the original question

Comment: The original question mentioned redshift.